# Single linkage hierarchical clustering - boxplots on height of the branches to detect outliers

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, outliers, euclidean-distance

before k-means clustering for consumer segmentation, I want to identify and delete outliers of my sample. I tried hierarchical clustering with single linkage algorithm. The problem is, I have a sample with more than 800 cases, and in my plot (single linkage dendrogram) the numbers are written across each other and therefore not readable, so it is impossible for me to clearly identify the outliers by just looking at the graph :-/

Here they say, you can create boxplots based on the branch distance to identify outliers in a more objective way. I thought that would be also a great way to just make the row numbers of the outliers in my dataset readable, however I am struggling with creating the boxplots..
https://link.springer.com/article/10.1186/s12859-017-1645-5/figures/3

Does anyone know, how to write the code to get the boxplots based on the height of the branches?

This is the code I use for clustering and attached you can see the plot

```
dr_dist<-dist(dr_ma_cluster[,c(148:154)])
hc_dr<-hclust(dr_dist,method = "single")      #single linkage
plot(hc_dr,labels=(row.names(dr_ma_cluster)))
```

[image: hard to read-dendrogram]

This is my failed trial to do the boxplot, as I don't know how to address the branch height

```
> boxplot(hc_dr)
Error in x[floor(d)] + x[ceiling(d)] : 
  non-numeric argument for binary operator
> boxplot(hc_dr[,c(148:154)])
Error in hc_dr[, c(148:154)] : Incorrect number of dimensions
```

And here another way to do the graph (and some automated outlier detection approach), but it makes the readability even worse with large datasets..
Another code to plot the tree, even less readable for large datasets:
[Delete outliers automatically of a calculated agglomerative hierarchical clustering data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46325350/delete-outliers-automatically-of-a-calculated-agglomerative-hierarchical-cluster)

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: seems like a lot of questions with no clear focus. to get the plot of the height, do ```boxplot(hc_dr$height)```

Comment: as for the readability, i don't see why you cannot extend the plot, reduce the size of the labels and add the option hang = -1 for example

Comment: Take a look a `dendextend` for your clustering visualization. It adds tons of options. For the boxplot, I'd just use ggplot since I really don't like base plot for this

Answer (score 0):

`boxplot(hc_dr$height)` as suggested by StupidWolf was the simple thing I was looking for.

Unfortunately I did not manage to label the outlier dots with the rownames from the original dataframe. Rownames from the branch height table were useless as they were assigned in ascending order.

`hang = 0.0001` gave a better look to the dendrogram, but labels were still unreadable as still over eachother.

If anyone has a similar problem check [R Shiny, zoomable dendrogram program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63286645/r-shiny-zoomable-dendrogram-program)

the code given there in the answer was super easy to adapt, resulting in a zoomable dendrogram, which makes it easy to identify the relevant cases (->outliers). for details search `dendextend`as proposed by csgroen.

Both together, the boxplot and this nice tool served to identify the rownames of the outliers after single linkage clustering in order to delete them before km means clustering